# Awk program for extracting unique values from a k1=v1,k2=v2,... list

Tags: strings, parsing, awk

A *single* string consisting of comma-separated pairs in the format `<key>=<value>`, like

```
ABC=https://host:443/topic1,DEF=https://host:443/topic1,GHI=https://host:443/topic3,JKL=https://host:443/topic3
```

must be converted to a line containing the unique set (for which the order does not matter) of *values,* separated by an empty space, i. e.:

```
https://host:443/topic1 https://host:443/topic3
```

via an Awk program.

The background idea is to convert one variant of CLI-arguments into another one in a shell script, like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

all_args="ABC=https://host:443/topic1,DEF=https://host1:443/topic1,GHI=https://host:443/topic3,JKL=https://host:443/topic3"
command1 $all_args
command2 $(echo $all_args | awk -f extractor.awk)
```

**The solution:**

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        split($i, arr, "=")
        vals[arr[2]] = arr[2]
    }
    for (v in vals) printf(v " ") 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array values are irrelevant.  Instead of

```
        vals[arr[2]] = arr[2]
```

you could use

```
        vals[arr[2]] = 1
```

to indicate you're storing flags in `vals`, and it is the keys that are important later, not the values.

If your input is guaranteed to be "well formed", and you can assume there is exactly one `,` between each pair, and one `=` inside each pair, you can separate fields on BOTH the comma and the equals characters.  Then you could extract every second field and flag those in your `vals` set.  This eliminates the need for `split()`.

```
BEGIN { FS="[,=]" }
{
        for( i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) {
                vals[$i] = 1
        }
        for (v in vals) printf(v " ")
}
```